# Tweaking the classloader used for import

Tags: clojure

When using the `import` form in Clojure, I would like that form to use the `JavaSourceClassLoader` of the [Janino library](https://janino-compiler.github.io/janino/) so that when trying to import a class, this custom loader will look inside a Java source directory and compile on-the-fly a Java class that gets imported.

At the root of my Leiningen project, I have a `dynjava/` directory where I put my Java source files. I wrote a bit of code to construct a JavaSourceClassLoader:

```
(ns playground.classloading
  (:import [org.codehaus.janino JavaSourceClassLoader])
  (:require [clojure.java.io :as io]))

(defn current-loader []
  (.deref clojure.lang.Compiler/LOADER))

(defn make-source-loader
  ([]
   (make-source-loader (current-loader)))
  ([parent]
   (JavaSourceClassLoader.
    parent
    (into-array [(io/file "dynjava")])
    nil)))
```

I have a sample file, `dynjava/Magic.java` that looks like this, in order to test it:

```
public class Magic {
    public int getNumber() {
        return 119;
    }
}
```

And I can actually, from within the REPL, compile, load and create instances of this class, e.g.

```
(.getNumber (.newInstance (.loadClass (make-source-loader) "Magic")))
;; => 119
```

Now I would like to use the JavaSourceClassLoader with the `import` form, so I tried this:

```
(def src-loader (make-source-loader))

(.bindRoot clojure.lang.Compiler/LOADER src-loader)
(.set clojure.lang.Compiler/LOADER src-loader)


(println "The var is " clojure.lang.Compiler/LOADER)
(if (.isBound clojure.lang.Compiler/LOADER)
  (println "The compiler loader is "
           (.deref clojure.lang.Compiler/LOADER)))
```

which displays this:

> ```
> The var is  #<Var: --unnamed-->
> The compiler loader is  #object[clojure.lang.DynamicClassLoader 0x9b1fcd3 clojure.lang.DynamicClassLoader@9b1fcd3]
> playground.classloading>
> ```

From this output, it is clear that I do something wrong when trying to modify the `LOADER` var, because it is *not* an instance of `JavaSourceClassLoader`.

And trying to import the `Magic` class that I wrote before does not work:

```
;; (import 'Magic) results in an Error
```

**My question is:** How can I change the class loader used by `import` in Clojure to be an instance of JavaSourceClassLoader?

(By the way, I am aware of `lein-virgil` but I had some problems using it as my project grew larger.)